# Sonatype Nexus: Taking user backup

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I have recently started working on a repository management tool called **Sonatype Nexus** version 2.8.x. I wanted to take a backup of nexus repositories as well as existing users. I am able to take repository backup by taking "sonatype-work" directory as a tar file.

Can anybody help me out, how to take the backup of existing users??

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A backup of the "sonatype-work" directory will contain the user configuration.

The users are listed in the following file:

> $SONATYPE_WORK/nexus/conf/security.xml

Comment: I have taken backup of this file, but when I restored it, users not came. Is there any configuration I need to do to get old users?

Comment: Sounds odd... Nexus doesn't use a database, only the files in that dir and a set of indexes. Is this an upgrade? (difference in versions?) One last thing to try is to regenerate the indexes. Sources: blog.sonatype.com/2011/06/nexus-tips-and-tricks-backup-nexus/ and http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-dirs.html

Comment: Back up the entire "sonatype-work/nexus/conf" directory, not just security.xml.